# Vue.js and D3.js - force-simualtion

Tags: javascript, vue.js, d3.js, axios

I'm currently trying to consume an Restful-Api call and use the infromation, to make an d3.js force-simulation. The problem is that if I use the data from an API, call the simulation handles it if there was nothing. If I wait for the next tick `this.$nextTick(simu)` all positions end up as an `NaN`. Is there a reason for this behaviour?

```js
const URL = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts';

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      webGraph: {
        nodes: [],
        edges: []
      },
      graph1: {
        nodes:[
          {url:2},
          {url:3},
        ],
        edges:[
          {source:2, target:3},
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  created() {
    axios.get(URL).then((response) => {
      let node1 = {
        url: response.data[1].id
      }
      let node2 = {
        url: response.data[2].id
      }
      let edge = {
        source: {url:response.data[1].id},
        target: {url:response.data[2].id}
      }
      this.webGraph.nodes.push(node1)
      this.webGraph.nodes.push(node2)
      this.webGraph.edges.push(edge)
    })
    
  d3.forceSimulation(this.webGraph.nodes)
      .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody().strength(-25))
      .force("link", d3.forceLink().id(d => d.url).links(this.webGraph.edges))
      .on('end', function() {
        console.log("done")
      });
  d3.forceSimulation(this.graph1.nodes)
      .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody().strength(-25))
      .force("link", d3.forceLink().id(d => d.url).links(this.graph1.edges))
      .on('end', function() {
        console.log("done")
      });
  

  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/6.2.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <h6>{{webGraph}}</h6>
  <br> 
  <h6>{{graph1}}</h6>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why `webGraph` and `graphData1` have different outcomes, is that the simulation of `webGraph` is started before it has data. If you move the `simulation` code inside inside the `axios.get().then`, then you'll see it works as you'd expect.

```js
const URL = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts';

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      webGraph: {
        nodes: [],
        edges: []
      },
      graph1: {
        nodes:[
          {url:2},
          {url:3},
        ],
        edges:[
          {source:2, target:3},
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  created() {
    axios.get(URL).then((response) => {
      let node1 = {
        url: response.data[1].id
      }
      let node2 = {
        url: response.data[2].id
      }
      let edge = {
        source: node1,
        target: node2
      }
      
      this.webGraph = {
        nodes: [node1, node2],
        edges: [edge]
      };
      
      d3.forceSimulation(this.webGraph.nodes)
        .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody().strength(-25))
        .force("link", d3.forceLink().id(d => d.url).links(this.webGraph.edges))
        .on('end', function() {
          console.log("done")
        });
    })

  d3.forceSimulation(this.graph1.nodes)
      .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody().strength(-25))
      .force("link", d3.forceLink().id(d => d.url).links(this.graph1.edges))
      .on('end', function() {
        console.log("done")
      });
  

  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/6.2.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <h6>{{webGraph}}</h6>
  <br> 
  <h6>{{graph1}}</h6>
</div>
```

In your code, I also changed the initialization of `edge`. It showed that you need to look at the difference between *variables* and *references*.

With `let edge = { source: {url:response.data[1].id}, target: {url:response.data[2].id} }`, if `node1` changes, `edge.source` does not. So `edge.source` will not know where to point to. With `let edge = { source: node1, target: node2 }`, the code is not only shorter, but if `node1` changes, `edge.source` is always up to date.